# Connection String for ODBC on report server

Tags: excel, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I want to create a datasource on report server from an excel. I put my excel to report server. Than i wrote a connection string, but it did not work. What is wrong? "Data Source=http://xxxxx.com;Initial Catalog=MyExcelName"

Answer (score 0):

Connection string to Excel depends on provider you use. For example, for `Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0` provider connection string should looks like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";
```

Note that data source points to local file. I do not think that you can point to data source through http.

More information about connection strings to Excel can be found at https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/.

PS: To access data from query here is an example: `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]`. This query retrieve all data from first sheet of excel workbook.